# PowerBI embed local .pbix

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I would like to render a local PBIX file without having to upload the PBIX file to Azure cloud and afterwards include the required attributes in the embed div.

So far, I haven't even been able to find documentation on how this could be achieved, nor any library for locally rendering a PBIX file, nor even documentation on the .pbix format itself.

The code is run on Node.js, therefore I am looking for an implementation written in Javascript.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

That is not currently available as a Power BI feature. However a [preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/01/18/getting-started-with-the-technical-preview-of-power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services/) of SQL Server Reporting Services vNext contains the ability to render Power BI reports and that could be installed on prem or on your laptop.

If I recall right, the preview is limited to SSAS data sources at the moment.

**Update: It is called [Power BI Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/?) now.**

Comment: Thank you for your response. The SQL Server Reporting Services vNext is actually quite a thing I have been looking for!

Comment: Yet I don't feel like this is a proper implementation for my Node.js program. It has only access to PBIX files to aid in the rendering of PBIX files.

Comment: @jervtub I think Power BI Embedded is probably the right way to go in my opinion. Why the concern with publishing the pbix to the cloud?

Comment: Currently I have to publish the PBIX file to the Azure cloud in order to retrieve it with Power BI Embedded from the Azure cloud. I wonder if there is a method to keep the PBIX file local without having to upload it first to Azure cloud.

Comment: @jervtub there is not